# C# - Updating an ID that requires guessing an AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: c#, mysql

Ok, so in my MySQL Database, I have a table called groups. In that table, there is one column called id and one column called group_id. Both are needed. Groups are inserted via a C# Emulator. I need to know, how can I edit my code to make it match id and group_id in the database? id is an AUTO_INCREMENT in my groups table and is the primary key.

Here is my C# code,

```
queryreactor.setQuery(string.Concat(new object[]
                {
                    "INSERT INTO groups (`name`, `desc`,`badge`,`owner_id`,`created`,`room_id`,`colour1`,`colour2`) VALUES(@name, @desc, @badge, ",
                    Session.GetHabbo().Id,
                    ", UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ",
                    RoomId,
                    ",'",
                    Colour1,
                    "','",
                    Colour2,
                    "')"
                }));
                queryreactor.addParameter("name", Name);
                queryreactor.addParameter("desc", Desc);
                queryreactor.addParameter("badge", Badge);
```

Anyone any ideas? I know MySQL doesn't support 2 AUTO_INCREMENT columns. But, I basically just need to match the id column and group_id column.

Comment: so what you want is that the group id column should have same value as id column?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html

Comment: @Codeek yes, exactly

Codemonkey, I'm a little confused. I'm new to C# still, so no clue how to add that into my application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why you need two columns just to have exactly same values, because you can always use ID column for both group_Id and ID.

If you still want to have such columns, then a simple solution would be to
fire an update query after your Insert query where your group_id gets updated with your newly inserted id column.

something like

```
update groups
set group_id = id
where group_id is null
```

or even better, **[write a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)** on your `groups` table so that your group_id column gets updated automatically with that of `id` column on an insert statement of the row